# Can I call an initialized object again?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have a JavaScript constructor function that I want to use to fetch some data asynchronously via Ajax first, and once that's done, call itself again to manipulate the fetched data. This basically means calling the same instance of the constructor function again, but I can't get it to work. Here is a skeleton of what I'm trying to do:

```
function ajaxmenu(file){
    var filefetched = false
    var instance = this // save reference to this instance of ajaxmenu
    if (!filefetched){
        $.get(file, function( data ){
            $(data).appendTo(document.body)
            filefetched = true
            instance() // how can I call instance again to initialize menu again now that ajax file is loaded?
            return
        })
    }

    this.menu = $('#menuid') // uses jQuery
    this.menu.css({width: '100px'})
    //do something else fancy with $menu
}

var menu = new ajaxmenu('menu.htm')
```

So basically the logic I want to happen here is, when `ajaxmenu()` is instantiated, the portion inside `ajaxmenu()` that fetches some file via Ajax is called, then once that's done, the same instance of `ajaxmenu()` is called again, but this time with the file in place already for the reminder of the function to parse and manipulate.

How can I do this? What I have now, calling `instance()` returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the answer to your question `Can I call an initialized object again` is yes! You have many options.

If you insist to use the same function again, then one option would be to

- add a second parameter `filefetched` to `ajaxmenu`
- you do not need the `var instance = this;`
- pass a `true` when calling the `ajaxmenu` from itself, to skip the fetching: `ajaxmenu(file, true);`

Full code:

```
function ajaxmenu(file, filefetched){
    if (!filefetched){
        $.get(file, function( data ){
            $(data).appendTo(document.body)
            ajaxmenu(file, true);
        });
    }

    this.menu = $('#menuid') // uses jQuery
    this.menu.css({width: '100px'})
    //do something else fancy with $menu
}

var menu = new ajaxmenu('menu.htm', false);
```

Another option (without a self-call) would be to use the callbacks that jQuery offers with the [get function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and do your change to the menu in the `done` event, that is executed once the `get` function completes. This way you don't need the recursive call:

```
function ajaxmenu(file){
    $.get(file, function( data ){
        $(data).appendTo(document.body)
    })
    .done(function() {
        this.menu = $('#menuid') // uses jQuery
        this.menu.css({width: '100px'})
        //do something else fancy with $menu
    });
}

var menu = new ajaxmenu('menu.htm');
```

This also simplifies the code a lot, because you don't need branches (and/or recursive calls) and it is much more readable and so better maintainable.

Generally on recursive calls: you always need a condition to stop the recursion to prevent an infinite loop. One possibility would be using a parameter that is change on every new recursive call:

```
function process(data, n)
{
    // process data
    // iterate again or stop recursion
    if (n > 0)
    {
        process(data, n - 1);
    }
    // done => n = 0
}
// start
process(data, 5);
```

Another option would be using a global variable and track it's state, but this generally indicates a bad design and it is not recommended:

```
// global variable
var n = 5;
function process(data)
{
    // process data
    // iterate again or stop recursion
    if (n > 0)
    {
        n = n - 1;
        process(data);
    }
    // done => n = 0
}
// start
process(data);
```

Comment: Thanks Pasty, your solution is a good start, though when `ajaxmenu(file, true);` is called inside the ajax function, it isn't actually calling the previously instantiated version of `ajaxmenu()`, which I need. I need to do branching inside the ajax function using `return` at the end so the reminder of the constructor function doesn't get called until the file is fetched, when elements inside the file become available. If I just call `ajaxmenu(file, true);` the 2nd time, the object `this` points to the global object instead of the previously initiated object.

Comment: I'm aware of the 2nd approach, though I want to avoid putting everything inside a callback function.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) about the `this` keyword in JavaScript. It's behaviour in JavaScript is different as in C/C++/Java/C# because JavaScript uses lexical scoping. If you want to use the `this` instance then pass it also as parameter to `ajaxmenu`.